# Overflow by converting hex to decimal manually in C#

Tags: c#, hex, decimal, overflow

my task is to write a program using loops that converts a hexadecimal integer number to its decimal form.Do not use the built-in .NET functionality.

I've written the program and it works for all tests except for "4ED528CBB4" and it overflows after "D". I use long for the result and I can't find the issue.

```
        string hexadecimal = Console.ReadLine();
        long result = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < hexadecimal.Length; i++)
            {

                if (hexadecimal[hexadecimal.Length - i - 1] >= '0' && hexadecimal[hexadecimal.Length - i - 1] <= '9')
                {
                    result += ((hexadecimal[hexadecimal.Length - i - 1] - '0') * (int)Math.Pow(16, i));
                }
                else if (hexadecimal[hexadecimal.Length - i - 1] == 'D')
                {
                    result += (13 * (int)Math.Pow(16, i));
                }
                else if (hexadecimal[hexadecimal.Length - i - 1] == 'C')
                {
                    result += (12 * (int)Math.Pow(16, i));
                }
                else if (hexadecimal[hexadecimal.Length - i - 1] == 'A')
                {
                    result += (10 * (int)Math.Pow(16, i));
                }
                else if (hexadecimal[hexadecimal.Length - i - 1] == 'B')
                {
                    result += (11 * (int)Math.Pow(16, i));
                }
                else if (hexadecimal[hexadecimal.Length - i - 1] == 'F')
                {
                    result += (15 * (int)Math.Pow(16, i));
                }
                else if (hexadecimal[hexadecimal.Length - i - 1] == 'E')
                {
                    result += (14 * (int)Math.Pow(16, i));
                }

            }
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Try unsigned integer

Comment: Change all of your casts from `(int)` to `(long)` and it works for me. Also you might want to add `checked()` around the operations which will throw an exception on overflow (if it overflowed enough it would become positive again and you might not even notice it overflowed): `result += checked((13 * (long)Math.Pow(16, i)));`. I only looked briefly but it looked like the `13 * (int)Math.Pow()` is what overflowed where the cast to `int` went OK but multiplying by 13 is was pushed it over `int`'s limits.

Comment: Tanks for the answer. I added `checked` and changed everything to `long`and now there is an overflow message . How can such a problem be fixed?

Comment: You get an error on the same string, `"4ED528CBB4"`? You probably missed a `(long)` conversion. Search for "(int)" and make sure you replace all of them. After I did that i get the same answer as [here](http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter) without any exceptions.

Comment: Yes, I had missed one in the first case. Now it works properly. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If your `reult` parameter is `long`, shouldn't you be doing type casting in that?